# OpenVPN asks for key passphrase on an unencrypted key

Tags: openvpn

I've been using OpenVPN on Windows 10 for years to connect to a remote network. Not a single problem. The remote server runs either on a Raspberry Pi or a Windows PC (can't look it up now). Authentication uses key files that I've generated with the application "xca", a Windows CA and key management tool. The key is then exported into a single .p12 file.

On my new Windows 11 computer, that doesn't work anymore. OpenVPN 2.6.5 asks me for a key passphrase before trying to connect. The key doesn't have a passphrase. Empty input is not allowed, I can only cancel that dialogue. What's the problem here? Is there a bug in OpenVPN? Should I use an older version that works better?

Some discussions about such issues suggest to enable some compatibility mode in some OpenSSL config file. I cannot apply this on my Windows computer.